# Provider.of<AppBarCubit>(context, listen: false)

Tags: flutter, flutter-dependencies, flutter-animation

I am trying to create a customer app bar which fades as you scroll and then maintains its state if you were to swap to and from without resetting everything.however the fade has stopped working after I implemented bloc and cubit.

When I start scrolling on my app it throws an exception:

```
"Tried to listen to a value exposed with provider, from outside the widget tree."
```

and then suggests:

```
To fix write "Provider.of<AppBarCubit>(context, listen: false);"
```

It also says likely cause by an event handler. But when I add this to anywhere it doesn't work.

Im not sure where i should be implementing this or how to implement this. apologies in advance as I beginner at this.

This is my code:

```
class _HomeScreenState extends State<HomeScreen> {
  ScrollController _scrollController;



@override
  void initState() {
    _scrollController = ScrollController()
      ..addListener(() {
        context.watch<AppBarCubit>().setOffset(_scrollController.offset);
      });
    super.initState();
  }

  @override
  void dispose() {
    _scrollController.dispose();
    super.dispose();
  }

  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    final Size screenSize = MediaQuery.of(context).size;
    return Scaffold(
      extendBodyBehindAppBar: true,
      floatingActionButton: FloatingActionButton(
        backgroundColor: Colors.grey[850],
        child: const Icon(Icons.cast),
        onPressed: () => debugPrint('Cast'),
      ),
      appBar: PreferredSize(
        preferredSize: Size(screenSize.width, 50.0),
        child: BlocBuilder<AppBarCubit, double>(
          builder: (context, scrollOffset) {
            return CustomAppBar(scrollOffset: scrollOffset);
          },
        ),
      ),
      body: CustomScrollView(
        controller: _scrollController,
        slivers: const [
          SliverToBoxAdapter(
            child: ContentHeader(featuredContent: sintelContent),
          ),
          SliverPadding(
            padding: EdgeInsets.only(top: 20.0),
            sliver: SliverToBoxAdapter(
              child: Previews(
                key: PageStorageKey('previews'),
                title: 'Previews',
                contentList: previews,
              ),
            ),
          ),
          SliverToBoxAdapter(
            child: ContentList(
              key: PageStorageKey('myList'),
              title: 'My List',
              contentList: myList,
            ),
          ),
          SliverToBoxAdapter(
            child: ContentList(
              key: PageStorageKey('originals'),
              title: 'Netflix Originals',
              contentList: originals,
              isOriginals: true,
            ),
          ),
          SliverPadding(
            padding: EdgeInsets.only(bottom: 20.0),
            sliver: SliverToBoxAdapter(
              child: ContentList(
                key: PageStorageKey('trending'),
                title: 'Trending',
                contentList: trending,
              ),
            ),
          ),
        ],
      ),
    );
  }
}
```

Answer (score 1):

Do not use context.watch in the init function rather use context.read. In your build method, you can use context.watch. This would work.

Comment: As it’s currently written, your answer is unclear. Please [edit] to add additional details that will help others understand how this addresses the question asked. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).